# Can we use same Configmap for different volume mounts?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

Two pods are running and have different volume  mounts, but there is a need of using the same configmap in the 2 running pods.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do that. You can mount same `ConfigMap` into different volume. You can take a look into [configure-pod-configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

Say, your `ConfigMap` is like following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
  namespace: default
data:
  SPECIAL_LEVEL: very
  SPECIAL_TYPE: charm
```

And two pods:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod-01
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod-02
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Now see the logs after creating the above `ConfigMap` and two `Pods`:

```
# for 1st Pod
$ kubectl logs -f dapi-test-pod-01
SPECIAL_LEVEL
SPECIAL_TYPE

# for 2nd Pod
$ kubectl logs -f dapi-test-pod-02
SPECIAL_LEVEL
SPECIAL_TYPE
```

Comment: I am getting an error like "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
  what():  basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file"

Comment: @Nancy Have yuo tried? It's working for me and should work for you too.

Comment: can we change this "volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config" to volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume-2
        mountPath: /etc/config-2, for one of the pods? ... and config map remains same

Comment: Let me try and post the result.

Comment: You can use name whatever you wish by following the rule for the name field

Comment: I am getting the error like " terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure' what(): basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file"  by changing the name field.The example given above works fine... We have a situation where the name needs to be different in the name field.

Comment: @Nancy What name did you use? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#names has specification for it.

Comment: Hi Shudipta, it worked when i gave the exact mount path of the json file.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma , Thanks problem seems to be resolved now

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma can we have different logs for same config map?

Comment: @Nancy Actually it depends. Based on what images are in the pods' `spec.containers[]`, the log will be different.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma: can you also please look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038569/can-we-use-data-as-a-yaml-file-instead-of-json-file-in-config-map