# Can we use "data" as a yaml file instead of Json file in Config map

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

lets take this example of a config map

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  abc.yml: |-
<yml here>
```

Getting an error like failed to parse yaml to Json.

Comment: remove '-' from abc.yml: |- and try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but you should care about the syntax. You can also follow techniques for yaml from [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques.md#strings-in-yaml).

If you use `kubectl create configmap myconfig --from-file=abc.yml`, then it is ok.

But if you write the whole yaml file for your configmap in myconfig.yaml and then run `kubectl create -f myconfig.yaml`, then you should care about syntax.

Say your `abc.yml` file is as followings:

```
a:
  b: b1
  c: c1
d: d1
```

Then write your `myconfig.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  abc.yml: |
    a:
      b: b1
      c: c1
    d: d1
```

Now just run `kubectl create -f myconfig.yaml`.
That's it.

Happy Kubernetes!!!.

Answer (score 1):

Create `ConfigMap` from file.

`kubectl create configmap myconfig --from-file=youfile.yml`.

You can check more examples on [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

Answer (score 1):

These could be the problems
1. most likely the issue could with the indentation.
2. remove '-' from abc.yml: |- and check

I followed the below steps and was able to load yaml file into configmap. it worked fine.

```
master $ cat c.yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  redis-config: |
    maxmemory 2mb
    maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example-redis-config
```

```
master $ kubectl create configmap  testcfg --from-file=./c.yaml
```

```
master $ kubectl get cm testcfg -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  c.yaml: |
    apiVersion: v1
    data:
      redis-config: |
        maxmemory 2mb
        maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: example-redis-config
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2019-03-07T08:35:18Z
  name: testcfg
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "7520"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/testcfg
  uid: f033536d-40b3-11e9-a67d-0242ac11005b
```

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  abc.yml: |
 namespace: "a_namespace"
  :development:
  <<: *defaults
  deployment >> default 
How to make the config map read the default variables ?

Comment: please state clearly what exactly you are trying to achieve